# Setting the MODULE_PATH variable for default env of spack

Tags: environment-modules, spack

Lately, the mechanism used by Spack to manage the modules (I refer to the Environment Modules and to LMod) changed a little bit to allow a better integration with the spack environments (see pull request #23703).

Unfortunately, this also affect the fact that Spack does not update anymore the MODULE_PATH variable by default; indeed, the documentation still reports that

> If you have installed a supported module system you should be able to run either module avail or use   -l spack to see what module files have been installed.

but, at least on my machine, after installing a few packages, the module avail command does not show any new module (I am using commit 9936182). I suppose that this happens because now Spack want to know which environment should be loaded.

Of course,the problem could be easily fixed by adding the directory with the modules in the MODULE_PATH env var, but I am not sure that this is the best practice.
Is there a way to say to spack: "please, load the modules of the default environment?"

Thank you